# Back and Forward navigation arrows in gmail search

Tags: navigation, search, search-suggestion

I've been trying to figure out what these back and forward errors are meant for in gmail search view. They seem to always remain in a disabled state while the 'Done' button is always enabled. I thought they were for navigating between long search keywords but that doesn't seem to be the case either. Even if they aren't for that purpose, is it a good idea to have these arrows to shift cursor between keywords?

Btw in gmail compose view, these arrows are meant to navigate between fields.

> [image: gmail search view]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These controls are not part of Gmail but part of your OS, iOS in this case. They are always there whenever you access an input field. If there's only one on the page then both arrows are disabled. If there are two or more on the page then you can use the arrows to navigate between them.

Comment: But the screenshot that I attached is from their iOS app :S

Comment: Sorry, my fault. It's part of the OS, not the browser.